# How can I find out who is behind a Mac address?

Tags: mac-address, bluetooth

I was connecting a bluetooth device to my tablet and noticed that when scanning for the devices one "device" was actually a Mac address. We (me and my husband) have been under a hacker attack already a month and I'm concerned about this Mac address. Those hackers messed up my husbands phone, it has been acting up ever since those hackers penerated trough modem, router and firewall.

Anyway, now I'm worried if they are trying to mess my tablet and phone too! I also noticed that my phone is "visible to all nearby Bluetooth devices". Before I was able to choose if I wanted to be visible or not.

So, I would really like to know who is behind that address. At least if it is a new attempt to sneak in by our network that our devices share.

These guys are not giving up!

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'one "device" was actually a Mac address'? Each device with a network interface card will have a MAC address...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trace the owner of a computer by mac address](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79571/how-to-trace-the-owner-of-a-computer-by-mac-address)

Answer (score 2):

Technically there is no way to couple a MAC address to a person. MAC addresses are easily spoofed. In case the attackers were careless and didn't spoof their MAC address, you can at best try to identify the device vendor (http://www.macvendorlookup.com/).

If your tablet or phone are compromised it's best to install them from scratch (from a computer you know is not compromised). Also take care not to jailbreak/root your phones as this often leaves them more vulnerable as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find out the ip of the attacker by listing your [arp table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol). Unfortunately, in your case his local ip probably won't help a lot, but in similar cases maybe you can have a luck. And in the case of a bluetooth device, there isn't always an IP address on it.

If your hw/sw is capable to measure the signal strength of the remote devices, you can find his physical position with that. (Please, don't hurt him - maybe he is only a boy in the neighborhood playing with his new mobile device.) There are numerous bluetooth signal strength meters, and even triangulator applications for android, and so is it probably with other hw/sw evironments, too.